# Vanilla js isn't working on my rails app?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

i'm trying to implement a full screen menu, I don't get any rails errors but when I run the project it doesn't work at all. I get this error when I go to inspect element:

```
Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
```

Here is my js:

```
(function() {

  var Menu = (function() {
    var burger = document.querySelector('.burger');
    var menu = document.querySelector('.menu');
    var menuList = document.querySelector('.menu__list');
    var brand = document.querySelector('.menu__brand');
    var menuItems = document.querySelectorAll('.menu__item');

    var active = false;

    var toggleMenu = function() {
      if (!active) {
        menu.classList.add('menu--active');
        menuList.classList.add('menu__list--active');
        brand.classList.add('menu__brand--active');
        burger.classList.add('burger--close');
        for (var i = 0, ii = menuItems.length; i < ii; i++) {
          menuItems[i].classList.add('menu__item--active');
        }

        active = true;
      } else {
        menu.classList.remove('menu--active');
        menuList.classList.remove('menu__list--active');
        brand.classList.remove('menu__brand--active');
        burger.classList.remove('burger--close');
        for (var i = 0, ii = menuItems.length; i < ii; i++) {
          menuItems[i].classList.remove('menu__item--active');
        }

        active = false;
      }
    };

    var bindActions = function() {
      **burger.addEventListener('click', toggleMenu, false);**
    };

    var init = function() {
      bindActions();
    };

    return {
      init: init
    };

  }());

  Menu.init();

}());
```

This is my first time using vanilla - are there extra steps that I'm missing in order to use it in rails? (via 'require' or something? or is it built in? Thanks!

my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>

<title>AaP</title>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>
<%= javascript_include_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track' => true %>

<%= csrf_meta_tags %>

</head>

<body>

<div class="header">
<h1>ASHLEIGH</font> <font color=#f6f6f6>/</font> <font color=#fbe2d4>ALMEIDA</font></h1>
  <div class="burger">
    <div class="burger__patty"></div>
    <div class="burger__patty"></div>
    <div class="burger__patty"></div>
  </div>
<nav class="menu">
    <div class="menu__brand">x
      <a href=""><div class="logo"></div></a>
    </div>
    <ul class="menu__list">
      <li class="menu__item"><a href="" class="menu__link">About</a></li>
      <li class="menu__item"><a href="" class="menu__link">Work</a></li>
       <li class="menu__item"><a href="" class="menu__link">Contact</a></li>
      <li class="menu__item">
        x</i></a>
      </li>
      <li class="menu__item">
        x
          <i class="fa fa-dribbble"></i></a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</div>
```

Comment: Do you get any errors in console?

Comment: do you have any HTML element with class "burger"?

Comment: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null" :)

Comment: @PavelGatnar - yup,  <div class="burger">

Comment: do you run your JS when the DOM is ready?

Comment: @PavelGatnar I edited my post and added my html file - hopefully that helps - thanks ! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you get the error is that the script is executed before the DOM is loaded and parsed. So there is not "burger" div at this time.

Wrap your code with the DOMContentLoaded handler,
see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded

Comment: okay so I added the code to the top of my js file, now I get:

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
application.self-40b20bf8c64be14ddd15703a095a78137b6078d743ab579da88d8b157be541f6.js:19 DOM fully loaded and parsed

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell it's saying that burger is null. Which would lead me to think that your Javascript is executing before the DOM is loaded.

If I'm correct, in order to fix this you would have to look at the order things are being loaded. Currently by default the javascript is being loaded at the

`<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>`.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "Example" %></title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "vendor/modernizr" %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  </head>

  <body>
    <%= render "static_pages/header" %>
    <%= yield %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
  </body>
</html>
```

So I would say move the

`<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>` under the `<%= yield %>`

line and see if that works.